# Каким образом мне нужно реализовать алгоритм градиентного спуска?

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, градиент

У меня есть задача минимизировать функцию методом градиентного спуска. Допустим, функция вида y=ax+b. Пользователь вводит точки, а программа должна минимизировать параметры a и b. То есть найти такие a и b, при которых функция минимальна. Мне удалось найти множество материалов о градиентном спуске, но я не могу понять как применить его конкретно к этой задаче.
Если я возьму производные по a и b, то по а будет х, а по b — 1. Но тогда они не будут меняться при изменении параметра и я не знаю как это подберёт мне a и b.
Я определённо что-то делаю не так, помогите пожалуйста.
Если это важно, я пишу на C#

Comment: "программа должна минимизировать параметры a и b" - это неправильная фраза. До и после правильно написано. А вообще там нужно считать направление градиента и делать шаг, только не помню в направлении градиента или антиградиента. Шаг делается не на весь градиент, а на какую-то его долю, например на 0.01 В общем, почитайте ещё матчасть, я сам не помню, всё не объясню.

Comment: Эта задача слишком проста для градиентного спуска. Он её решит в один шаг и этот шаг - решение системы линейных уравнений методом Гаусса.

Comment: Если бы всё решалось простым чтением учебника, моя жизнь была бы куда проще.